# How to show negative time in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to show negative time in a cell?

eg: if I need to calculate work hours balance

- day 1 : from 8:00 to 16:00 (8:00 hours = standard)
- day 2 : from 8:00 to 19:00 (+3 hours)
- day 3 : from 8:00 to 12:00 **(-4 hours)**

I use excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

`C2=HOUR((B2-A2)-INT(B2-A2))-8`

Where Column A=Start Time, B=End Time and C=Time Difference

Row-1 is Header Row

Format Difference Column "C" as Number

I do not have sufficient points to post the image. :(

Comment: HOUR() is being used not on (B2-A2) as you have implied but over (B2-A2) - INT(B2-A2)

Comment: If you still want to include an image, post a link to it at any sharing site you use.  You should be able to do that in a comment.  If you "address" the comment like I did here, I'll be alerted to your posting and I can embed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume start time is in A2 and end time is in B2.  If the times can straddle midnight, they must be entered as date+time.

Date+time is stored as a number.  The integer portion is the number of days since a reference date.  Time is stored as a decimal fraction of a day.  You can do normal math on these values.

In C2, the formula would be:

```
=(B2-A2)*24 - 8
```

B2-A2 gives you the time difference.  Multiplying by 24 converts the difference to hours.  Subtracting 8 compares the result to your 8 hour standard.

This will display as positive or negative hours, including decimal fractions of an hour.

Answer (score 1):

=(SUM(HOUR(B2), (MINUTE(B2)*(1/60)))-SUM(HOUR(A2), (MINUTE(A2)*(1/60)))-8)

Ensure the field you paste this formula is set to General or Number.  With some creative variable use you can change 8 to a cell reference instead if you have different jobs with different standard shift lengths.

Here's an example of what you can do.[image: Example of using variable for shift length]